# Get all available TFS Fields for a Project Collection

Tags: c#, tfs, command-prompt, tfs-sdk, tfs-process-template

I need all **Fields for a TFS Project Collection** without specifiying a workitem. I'm already using the TFS API for a few other things, but I haven't found anything on this.

What I found was using the **witadmin.exe listfields** command, which gives me exactly what I want, but how do I get the results as a *collection in my code*? I'm not very experienced with commands, I just need the **Field IDs and Names** in my code so that I can display them in a WPF Listview. Do I need to call cmd.exe in my code or does the **TFS API** have an **extension method** for this? My "teacher" said it should have one since it can be done with the witadmin.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`witadmin.exe` is a .NET Executable, so you can use Reflector, dotPeek or ilSpy on it to see how Microsoft has implemented it. This seems to be the snippet you're after:

```
protected void InitFields()
{
    if (this.fields == null)
    {
        FieldDefinitionCollection definitions = new FieldDefinitionCollection(this.Store, false);
        List<FieldDefinition> list = new List<FieldDefinition>(definitions.Count);
        Dictionary<string, FieldDefinition> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, FieldDefinition>(definitions.Count, this.Store.ServerStringComparer);
        for (int i = 0; i < definitions.Count; i++)
        {
            FieldDefinition item = definitions[i];
            if (!item.IsInternal)
            {
                list.Add(item);
                dictionary[item.ReferenceName] = item;
                dictionary[item.Name] = item;
            }
        }
        list.Sort(new FieldComparer(this.Store.ServerStringComparer));
        this.fields = list;
        this.fieldsMap = dictionary;
    }
}
```

It will generate a list of all available fields in the Collection.

`this.Store` is an instance of `WorkItemStore`.

Comment: I see, I didn't think you could look into an executable like that. What exactly is the FieldComparer? I can't find that type. The WorkItemStore I can get, but not the FieldComparer.

Comment: I don't know, when I try to build the Project, it cannot find type or namespace FieldComparer. How would the compiler find it? Is there a using reference I need?

Comment: Could I not just ignore the dictionary and the FieldComparer and return the list?

Comment: I see, so I don't really need the FieldComparer, I think I can sort it another way. I'll try this, I think I can work with that method, thank you very much, I'll comment again if there are any problems!